# Different databases on local machine and inside the docker container

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, port

I have created container from postgres image

[image]

with following code:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -d -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres
```

My problem is that the ports are the same but databases(on my local machine and docker container) are different and i don't understand why and how i can fix it...

Comment: You host database is not shared `volumes` with your container data. hve a look to `volumes` -- `-v /host/path/to/db:/containert/path/to/db`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please explain a little bit what _exactly_ you want to achieve? Your general question ("why") is very broad, and the "how" depends on what you want to do. :)

Comment: My goal is to download my created image and run it on any computer  to have access to my database)